# DLLs Not Copying to Dependents on Successful Build

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dll

I have a .NET EF solution structured as such:

- Business
- Contracts
- Web
- dependencies include Business

I've made changes to both the business project and the web project. Building each project independently succeeds. Building the entire solution succeeds. The Business DLL file within Business/bin updated; the Business DLL file within Web/bin did not. I've been working on this solution all week, but the latest Business DLL within the Web/bin folder was two days old. Copying the latest Business DLL directly into Web/bin fixed the problem.

**My question is**: why has my IDE (Rider, but it happens in VS too) stopped copying the updated DLL to the dependents?

This has happened a number of other times for me with various solutions, most notably where the site could no longer find `System.Web.MVC` when it had been working for months prior, even up to the day prior. I've had to change the csproj files to point directly at the copied-in missing DLLs, as well as spend hours trying to find the root cause.

Please help me.

I have already tried below things:

- Deleting obj and bin folders
- uninstalling all nuget packages
- build/clean/rebuild etc.
- delete the project and reclone
- switch back to master
- restart computer
- target secondary SSD in case it was a space issue
- within VS switching "Copy Local" from true to false to back to true
- confirming all folders have admin rights
- deleted and recreated the IIS site

**Note**: I always open my IDE as admin.